# What is the #includes: directive in Metacello?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, metacello

I don't understand the following excerpt. More precisely, it's not clear what the `#includes:` directive is since it looks exactly like the opposite of `#requires:`.

```
spec for: #'pharo3.x' do: [
    spec 
        package: 'Grease-Core' with: [
            spec includes: #('Grease-Pharo30-Core' ). ];
        package: 'Grease-Tests-Core' with: [
            spec includes: #('Grease-Tests-Pharo20-Core' ). ];
        package: 'Grease-Pharo30-Core' with: [
            spec requires: #('Grease-Core' ). ];
        package: 'Grease-Tests-Pharo20-Core' with: [
            spec requires: #('Grease-Tests-Core' ) ] ].
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an opposite to the requires but it does more. If `A requires: B` and `B includes: A`,
then loading `B` effects, that `A` is also loaded (because of `#includes:`) after `B` is loaded (because of `#requires`).

I had a discussion with Dale about this behavior. In the end, it is a naming issue. In the debian World, you would use something like `#provides:` (which is not existing), and you could write

```
A provides: B
```

However, the fact that still `A requires: B` would not be reflected there.

#### TL;DR

When `A includes: B`, then loading `A` also loads `B`.

Comment: From your explanation I get what `includes:` does but not what distinguishes it from `requires:`.

Comment: So, `A requires: B` says: “If you load `A`, you _previously_ have to load `B`.” But `A includes: B` says “If you want to load `A`, you _also_ have to load `B`”